# Java library to measure bandwith, latency, hop-count?

Tags: java

I would be very thankful for your help: Do you know any good Java Libraries that can easily be embedded in any Java application that help to measure at least the

- bandwidth
- latency
- hopcount

For example I have a file www.test.com/testfile.tmp and want to measure the aforementioned parameters in downloading the file. Do you know of a good library that can do this?

Thank you very much!!
Jan

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the apache commons network library: http://commons.apache.org/net/ . It'll have some of the things you need to measure. Echo is a powerful, yet restricted tool; most of the sites will have the echo function restricted, but if you are trying to measure within your own network, it'll help.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, install the YSlow plugin from Yahoo! which will give a very detailed breakdown on what is going on with your page and what you can do about it.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably make an external call to the Linux "mtr" command, which gives great information about latency, hops, loss, and standard deviation.  But, obviously that's only going to work in certain circumstances.  It does require root/suid, so that level of statistics probably isn't something you're going to be able to get from just a library.  It doesn't measure bandwidth though.

Answer (score -1):

While this is not a library per-se, it will provide information which I think is what you are getting at... http://getfirebug.com/

Really detailed page load profiling utility as well as a plethora of other website optimization tips.

Cheers!

Comment: Firebug will give you the latency and bandwidth, I'm not sure about hopcount, you will need something like traceroute to perform that.  That will need to be run in parallel with firebug and pointed at the domain name - e.g. www.stackoverflow.com, see - http://www.mysitespace.com/howtoping.asp